# Can't catch exception in background task

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, background, task

My problem is, if I debug the background task of my `Windows 8 Store App` and get an `Error` (while async method call). ***It doesn't jump into my catch statment***. 
The debugger jumps to the `deferral.Complete()` method at the end of the background task code (in the `Run` method of `IBackgroundTask`).

Here's my code:

```
public sealed class TileUpdater: IBackgroundTask {
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
        var defferal=taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        InstantSchedule();
        defferal.Complete(); // <- Debugger jumps over here after error
    }

    public static async void InstantSchedule() {
        try {
            [...]

            // Error occurs here
            IEnumerable<LogsEntity> logentities=
                account.IsAvailable
                    ?await TableStorage.FetchLogsAsync(account.Accountname, account.AccountKey, TileUpdater.RetrieveFilter())
                    :null;

            [...]
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            // Debugger doesn't break here 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Pretty normal, with what you posted anyway.  Document the code in your catch block better.  Does it have any observable side effects?  Use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to debug.

Comment: If your `catch` block is actually empty, then I wouldn't be surprised if the debugger didn't step "into" it. Try adding a "throw;" and put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: I have code in my catch block ... But it doesn't even step into it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InstantSchedule` method is `async void` and returns control to the `Run` just after call to `FetchLogsAsync`. As a result, it jumps to catch statement, but after `Run` method finishes.

You should make `InstantSchedule` method as `Task` and `await` on it:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
    var defferal=taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    await InstantSchedule();
    defferal.Complete();
}

public static async Task InstantSchedule() {
        [...]
}
```

Note, that `Run` method is also should be `async`.